# different colors on radio buttons when they are active in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have three radio buttons which have the same theme in jquery. If I select one of them, the color of the button will change to the color specified in my .ui-btn-active class in the css. My radio buttons are named Can meet, not sure and Decline. I want my Decline radio button to have a different color than the two others when it is selected (the color red).

I'm using Jquery mobile and have customized the css for which colors I want to have on the different themes and I have changed the .ui-btn-active to .ui-btn-active-a and .ui-btn-active-b and made them with different values. I have tried to switch between the two ui-btn-active classes without no luck, and I have tried the addClass(..) and removeClass(..) without luck. I made a method in my jquery-mobile.js which look like this:

```
 $.mobile.changeAction = function( activeBtn){
    $.mobile.activeBtnClass = activeBtn;
}
```

where my activeBtn parameter will be a string to choose which activeBtnClass I want to have. I think the problem is that I have problems refreshing the activeBtnClass after overriding it, I have tried some refreshing methodes without no luck.

As long as the radio buttons have different colors when active I will be very thankful.

Comment: Maybe this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777722/refreshing-jquerymobile-styling-on-radio-buttons-on-the-fly)  will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following styles should do the trick:
[image: Screenshot1 Vertically stacked]

```
.ui-radio:nth-child(1) .ui-icon-radio-on.ui-icon{
    background-color:green;
}
.ui-radio:nth-child(2) .ui-icon-radio-on.ui-icon{
    background-color:grey;
}
.ui-radio:nth-child(3) .ui-icon-radio-on.ui-icon{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

Sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/EAGgm/).

To style Horizontally stacked select options:

[image: Screenshot2 Horizontally stacked]

```
.ui-radio:nth-child(1) .ui-radio-on span.ui-btn-inner{
    background-color:green;
}
.ui-radio:nth-child(2) .ui-radio-on span.ui-btn-inner{
    background-color:grey;
}
.ui-radio:nth-child(3) .ui-radio-on span.ui-btn-inner{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

Sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAGgm/19/).

Comment: Thanks, but I use this in my fieldset: 

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" >

The icons in the buttons will therefore disappear and the buttons will turn blue when they are clicked. Im sorry that I didn't give this information, I thought it wouldn't mather.

Comment: Are you able to update this code to work with Jquerymobile 1.4.2 please? as you can see it no longer works (http://jsfiddle.net/vt2870vp/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create custom themes for all of the states that you might want? You can have multiple custom themes, and only use them when you'd like. I have 7 themes in my CSS, and this way you can always incorporate them later if you'd like without having to do so much custom coding.

You can just apply the theme with the `data-theme="f"` (or other letter swatch) element attribute.

Here's jQuery ThemeRoller 1.1.1 http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php. If you're just making small changes to the theme, such as an active state, just copy the theme, and make the changes and save as a new swatch. You can go from A-Z :)

Comment: Thanks! But how can I switch between active states(.ui-btn-active)? I have tried to made more than one active class for each view, but it still only respond to one. Here is my html code:

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...? Are you saying you're trying to programmatically change to an active state?

Comment: I had a problem with changing between different active colors for radio buttons (horizontal). I figured it out thanks to the other respond. Thanks for your respons.