# radio buttonset alternative to jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, radio-button

I'm looking for a jQuery radio-button replacement script or code snippet that behaves like jQuery UI's button set, converting `<input type="radio" value="1">` into buttons. I want to keep the radio buttons intact for styling flexibility, and because it's the better coding practice.

Looks and works fine as-is with jQuery UI, but it **adds 230 KB** to the page load, which I'd like to avoid if possible. Here's how it looks now ...

[image]

Anyone seen something that can make radio buttons appear as above, but **without using jQuery UI**?

If not, can anyone suggest an approach?

Comment: you may look for CSS webkit..

Comment: @neokio, why you want radio button as button. you can use 'button' as radio options... can i know for what?

Comment: i've updated the description with a graphic that demonstrates usage...

Comment: @neokio take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578628/different-colors-on-radio-buttons-when-they-are-active-in-jquery-mobile which may give any idea..

Comment: @karthik thanks for the link! i hadn't considered using jQuery Mobile for a desktop browser app ... is this common practice? it is a little smaller than jQueryUI in final KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny thing I was just looking at another person who wrote his own module to do the same thing:

Disclaimer: I have not contributed to or thoroughly evaluated it so use your judgement:

http://jquerymore.com/form-elements/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Radio-Buttons-Into-Grouped-Buttons-radiosforbuttons

Alt Link: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Radio-Buttons-Into-Grouped-Buttons-radios-for-buttons.html

**It uses JQuery and Bootstrap Css** hence might not fit in your criteria of lightweight. If you are already including Jquery then this might be an option.

[Rant]

> This answer helped the original author and he accepted it. It helped
>   many more until the guy with the original github project closed it.
>   Then somehow I got downvoted to 0. I am almost sorry to have helped
>   someone. A quick google search for 'radiosforbuttons'(the project name) would have led you to alternative pages
>   with the same thing and BTW you are welcome to edit answer to provide
>   updated links. But no, bunch of lazy thankless people would rather
>   vote down instead of helping. This place is turning rotten everyday.

[/End of Rant]

Comment: Those links returning 404

Comment: To those people downvoting - You thankless people, I dont maintain every github project out there. Now I have 0 points for an accepted answer that had helped the original author. This place is turning into a rot. BTW a quick google search for 'radiosforbuttons' would have led you to: http://jquerymore.com/form-elements/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Radio-Buttons-Into-Grouped-Buttons-radiosforbuttons . Lazy thankless bunch.